# How to implement a div handler/resizer that updates two divs?

Tags: jquery, html, underscore.js, zepto

I'm looking for a way to build a handler/resize as seen on jsfiddle (screenshot below). My app has two divs each with a height of 50% and I would like to find a way to allow the user to resize the divs just like in jsfiddle. What's the cleanest way to do this with JavaScript and/or jQuery. Thanks

[image: Resize Handler]

Comment: Have a look here to: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/downloads.cfm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use jQUeryUI `rezizeable` . http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Set resizeable on one div and use `alsoRezize` option to connect the other

Comment: Thanks but I don't see this plugin having handlebars like jsfiddle?

Comment: just a matter of css to create handle that looks like fiddle. Demos are all using jQUery UI css but you can use anything you want

Answer (score 3):

Using purely CSS3, you can achieve this using the `resize` property:

http://www.css3.info/preview/resize/

CSS:

```
div
{
    resize: both;
}
```

**The downside is it isn't supported by all browsers:**

http://caniuse.com/css-resize

Answer (score 2):

It's called "UI Layout". If you search for it, you'll find examples like [this one](http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!layout/layout-2).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var pstyle = 'border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; padding: 5px;';
    $('#layout').w2layout({
        name: 'layout',
        padding: 4,
        panels: [
            { type: 'top', size: 50, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'top' },
            { type: 'left', size: 200, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'left' },
            { type: 'main', style: pstyle, content: 'main' },
            { type: 'right', size: 200, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'right' }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```